# Discharging capacitor of laptop

Tags: laptop, power, capacitor

I would like to know what is the procedure for discharging capacitors of a laptop, as my laptop is not able to power up. The AC power light starts to blink as soon as it's plugged to the laptop.

Comment: It depends on the laptop. Usually, the easiest way is to disconnect the CMOS battery and wait overnight. But some laptops have a simpler way.

Comment: i have lenovo G570, i have removed all the wires from the main-board.

Answer (score 3):

The way to do this is, with the computer shut down, unplug the computer, remove the battery, and hold the power button down for 30 seconds. This is also called a reset, good for correcting certain issues that pop up with laptops. It essentially drains all the stored energy that remains in a laptop after shut down.

Edit 12-26-13

There may be another issue that your laptop has. If the only thing that blinks is the AC power light, check the power adapter itself or the battery. I have seen this happen in laptops with these at fault. Either way the battery may be dead

Comment: i tried doing that but it didn't work, the light on the AC power plug still blinks, and still the laptop is not starting up.