# System randomly gets stuck on Asus logo

Tags: windows-10, boot

My N552-VW Asus laptop randomly gets stuck on Asus logo and I have to push the power button to turn it off and on again so it might work and boot into windows but it might not work and get stuck again so I have to go for the second or third try. The operating system is windows 10 enterprise 64-bit (10.0, build 19045) and is partitioned on SSD drive
There are some other things that I face some times:

- "ME FW Downgrade Request ME Spilock Failed" Error message While booting
- Won't get out of sleep if it stays in it for something about an hour
- After the shutting down the power light stays On, but every other things sounds like is turned off and battery drains.

all the mentioned above might happen randomly and they're not happening all the time!
These are what I have done so far and not working:

- Changed the SSD to a new one
- Removed the HDD and just booting with SSD
- Updated to the latest BIOS firmware available N552VW.304
- Reinstall the Windows

Comment: @harrymc I mentioned windows

Comment: Stuck on logo means BIOS problem. Your BIOS is indeed the latest, so it might be hardware.

Comment: https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/a7-me-fw-downgrade-request-mespilock-failed.2636825/ One suggestion: bad RAM. Also: https://www.dell.com/community/XPS/XPS-15-9570-A7-Me-FW-Downgrade-Request-MeSpilock-failed-and-no/td-p/7626718/page/2 directions to reinstall Intel-Rapid-Storage-Technology-Driver-and-Management_V7C22_WIN_17.8.0.1065_A05.exe

Comment: "ME FW Downgrade Request ME Spilock Failed" is a definite firmware issue. see, for example: https://rog.asus.com/forum/showthread.php?104457-Error-during-boot-quot-Intel-ME-FW-Downgrade-failed-quot

Comment: @Amir - You really should consider addressing some of the feedback you have received, have you ruled out, bad system memory as being the culprit?  Additionally, you should try installing the most recent firmware just to rule out corrupt firmware install. All results on the later part of that error messages from multiple OEM(s) indicate it's a **firmware** issue. Which suggests the answer you already received is the answer to this question.

Comment: @Ramhound About previous comments I have to mention that obviously I have googled my problem and checked them, so I'm asking here. some of the ideas there are not compatible with my device though.

Comment: A quick search of my favorite search engine discovered similar reports after people installed the 304 firmware.  There seems to be consistency that downgrading to 300 solves this problem.  I won't make this an answer, as downgrading the BIOS is not supported and can be difficult (search: ["Asus N552VX stuck on logo after bios update" yayayo] ).

Answer (score 3):

Intermittent problems are a pain. Since it gets stuck at POST/BIOS/UEFI & because of the ME FW (intel **M**anagement **E**ngine **F**irm**W**are) message I suspect its something low-level (aka likely not Windows) as people have mentioned in the comments. Things to try:

1. If its still in warranty and/or you have money to pay for out-of-warranty support I'd engage Asus as I DO believe this may be a hardware issue
2. [Power drain/discharge](https://superuser.com/questions/1434220/what-does-pressing-the-power-button-on-a-laptop-with-no-power-do/1434229#1434229). Remove power cord & disconnect battery (you may have to open the bottom-cover/chassis to do this, let me know if you are uncomfortable doing that). Then hold power button for 30sec. This has fixed a lot of weird issues from my experience.
3. Try to update the ME FW. BIOS/FIRWARE page shows BIOS v202 came embedded with Intel ME FW seemingly indicating that is upgraded with the BIOS/FIRMWARE, but it seems to have failed. However it's unlikely & unwise to downgrade FW. So that route is out. [It looks like there are two items for ME drivers/FW](https://www.asus.com/us/supportonly/n552vw/helpdesk_download/) under: ['Chipset' (Intel Management Engine Interface)](https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/nb/DriversForWin10/MEI/MEI_Intel_15M_Win10_64_VER11061194.zip) & ['Others' (ASUS ME Update Tool)](https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/nb/N552VX/MEUpdate_VER1000.zip). Might be a good idea to note down the Intel Management Engine driver in Device Manager & try to get the FW version before installing those so you can CONFIRM if the installs/upgrades worked. If those don't help we can also try to find the drivers on Intel's site.
4. I'd try to replicate the issue with as little hardware attached as possible. Start by having NOTHING attached to laptop (no power cord, SD/memory chips, USB devices, etc.) then try to start it or wake from sleep. If issue still happens I'd try to remove the HDD/SDD & see if I can replicate in BIOS, special boot modes (diagnostics), or with a Linux live USB/CD booted.
5. Try to factory reset the BIOS. It MAY revert Secure Boot or TPM settings so could cause Windows to fail to boot so might be a good idea to write down some of the settings before resetting BIOS. Guessing you aren't too concerned as you have replaced the driver & reinstalled Windows. Dell has a BIOS recovery feature, unsure if Asus has, where if a BIOS flash/upgrade fails or you have POST issues you can hold certain keys at boot-up to trigger it, with desktops there is sometimes a jumper on the motherboard that can trigger this. This will take some time to research which I don't currently have, but may prove insightful to you
6. I've seen where certain graphics drivers cause a no-wake situation so confirm those are up to date