# Back USB3 ports stopped working after adding a new SSD

Tags: usb, ssd, motherboard, sata, usb-3

I've bought new Samsung 870 EVO SSD and connected it today to my PC with SATA cable coming from SSD caching port on motherboard

[image: SSDCACHE]

After that my back usb3 ports stopped working in general (no power supply even to keyboard).

I've reinstalled all drivers for motherboard ([ASUS P9X79 Deluxe](https://www.asus.com/supportonly/p9x79_deluxe/helpdesk_manual/)) even if they were installed already and still nothing.

[image: Back ports]

[image]

Comment: Those USB ports APPEAR to be soldered on the motherboard (mobo) so its not like a cable to them came loose. I suspect either the SSD mounted on motherboard is shorting something (try removing or unmounting) out OR it took a bit of static shock during your install. For the later I'd remove power cord & then hold power button for 10sec to drain the residual power in capacitors and such to give it a clean start, has fixed weird things for me in the past

Comment: SSD works ok, without issues, I see it and can use it. One thing I noticed was that SSD was identified as portable device. Is it possible that usb3 and that sata port has the same channels? I'll try the antistatic and see if it works

Comment: Even if the SSD is working, the metal on its outside could be shorting out something on the motherboard (for the USB-ports) based on how close it is to the circuitry

Comment: Apologies I thought the new SSD was the ASUS item in the first picture despite you mentioning it was a Samsung, doh! Google images reveals that ASUS is a heatsink on the mobo. I'd try to remove that black USB stick then try the other ports to see if they're working

Comment: ok @gregg, I've did the anti static trick with power off and power button, also cleaned the contacts with spirit on the back of motherboard where there was a fan attached to the case (I saw some weird stains/leakage there near the RAM contacts), I've rechecked all connections and now it works! Thank you very much, you can put your antistatic answer to this question so I can mark it correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe your motherboard took a bit of static shock during your SSD install. I think you should do a [power drain/discharge](https://superuser.com/a/1434229/160219): remove power cord & then hold power button for 10sec to drain the residual power in capacitors and such to give it a clean start, has fixed weird things for me in the past